# Can synchronous I/O be canceled automatically even if the driver doesn't complete irp?

Tags: windows, operating-system, io, driver, device-driver

In user mode code:

```
CreateFile(A device);
ReadFile(The device handle); // synchronously
```

In correspond driver's IRP_MJ_READ dispatch routine:

```
// To hold the irp. It will never complete the irp.
// This driver doesn't even have a cancel routine.
Sleep(INFINITE);
```

When I terminate the user mode app forcedly after do ReadFile(), can the I/O be canceled?
If it was asynchronous I/O, the app couldn't be terminated.
But if I/O is synchronous, does I/O manager cancel it automatically?

If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, both both asynchronous and synchronous I/O are implemented with IRPs.  The user-mode API ReadFile calls an internal NT API (system call) NtReadFile which ends up sending an IRP.  If the driver returns STATUS_PENDING, the NT API will return same status.  If the user-mode application makes a synchronous call to ReadFile, ReadFile will wait on the file handle for the I/O to complete.  The driver can also complete the IRP synchronously (regardless of the way the user-mode API is called).  I think that this is the case you are interested in.

IRPs are associated with the thread that sent them.  So when a **thread** is terminated (for example due to killing the process), the I/O manager attempts to cancel all the IRPs that are associated with that thread.   The thread cannot terminate until all the IRPs are completed.

When you close a handle, the I/O manager sends the driver IRP_MJ_CLEANUP, and IRP_MJ_CLOSE.  It is the **driver** that cancels pending IRPs (or just completes them as canceled) in this case.

The ability to cancel an IRP depends on the cooperation of the driver.  The driver must explicitly make the IRP cancelable by calling [IoSetCancelRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549674%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If the driver just blocks without making the IRP cancelable, the IRP will not get canceled.

Comment: First two sentences are right and clear. But 3th and 4th are little confused. For a driver which doesn't have a cancel routine, If I put a synchronous I/O and then do terminating process(or close handle), can the I/O be canceled?(because it was synchronous I/O). This is what I wanted to know. -I'm an English newbie.

Comment: By the way, in the your first sentense case, what if the driver doesn't have a cancel routine? Is it cancelable? how? I/O manager can't call cancel routine. And I/O could be processing still.

Comment: If the driver does not mark the IRP cancelable then the IO manager cannot cancel it.  This will keep the thread from terminating and the process will not terminate until the IRP completes.

Answer (score 3):

On Vista and up, you can use **[CancelSynchronousIo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelsynchronousio-func)** to mark all pending IO for a thread as canceled. [**NtCancelIoFile**](http://www.codewarrior.cn/ntdoc/win2k/io/NtCancelIoFile.htm) can be used to cancel IO for a specific file.  (disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this function)

The effects of these calls will vary, depending a.o. on the driver implementation.

Seen from the user mode application, the effect should be an immediate cancellation, even though the driver may keep waiting for a long time before the IO request is completely cleaned up.

MSDN: [I/O Completion/Cancellation Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/iocancel.mspx)  has a lot of information on cancellation:

> ### I/O Completion/Cancellation Guidelines
>
> The following are guidelines that all drivers that are shipped with or
>   intended to be used with Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 should
>   adhere to.
>
> Drivers written for previous versions of Windows may not automatically
>   satisfy these guidelines due to an important change for Windows Vista
>   and Windows Server 2008, namely support for cancellation of
>   IRP_MJ_CREATE IRPs.
>
> Use of the Windows Driver Foundation or Cancel-Safe IRP Queues library
>   is strongly recommended, because they automatically implement these
>   guidelines.
>
> **Definitions**
>
> **Reasonable period** means here less than 10 seconds for most operations and their cancellations. This time is derived from a user's
>   tolerance to delays when closing an application or canceling an I/O
>   operation that the user perceives is taking too long. It should be
>   much shorter for most operations. There may also be legitimate reasons
>   for it to be longer for some types of devices and/or operations.
>
> **IRPs** are issued by the I/O Manager on behalf of a user-mode application.
>
> **Long-term IRPs** are IRPs that take more than a reasonable period to complete.
>
> **Pend** means a driver should return STATUS_PENDING and mark the IRP pending.
>
> **Guidelines**
>
> - All IRPs (including Create) that can take an indefinite amount of time must be able to be cancelled. These are waits that block on
>     user-initiated events, for example named pipes or waiting for keyboard
>     input.
> - Close-IRPs should never block for more than a reasonable period.
> - All long-term IRPs should be pended. Drivers should not block a user-mode thread (for example, to acquire a mutex) inside its dispatch
>     routine for more than a reasonable period.
> - Whenever a driver pends an IRP, including Create, it must either:
> - Support IRP cancellation; or
> - Complete the operation within a reasonable period. This may require implementing time-outs. The only exception is for hardware that is
>     malfunctioning.
> - If a driver creates new IRPs that are passed to other drivers, then it must pass on cancellation or be able to disassociate these IRPs
>     from the original IRP issued by the I/O Manager.
> - All IRPs should be completed in a reasonable period once canceled. A driver that is about to complete an IRP for anything other than the
>     current thread must be suspension-proof. The only exceptions are
>     delays that are caused by hardware that is malfunctioning. If the
>     hardware is likely to malfunction frequently, then the driver should
>     have sufficient recovery mechanisms to complete the IRP in a
>     reasonable period.
> - A driver should never pend a canceled IRP.
> - Drivers should not have any path that would miss a cancellation unless the IRP will be completed shortly anyway (code just has to run
>     forward).